# Estruturas de dados - Lista diferenças

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada, typedef

Por favor gostaria de saber a real diferença entre essas estruturas abaixo:

```
typedef struct {
 int info;
 struct lista * prox
 struct lista * ant;
} tipo_lista;
```

e essa:

```
struct noCliente {
 int tempoUtilizandoMesa;
 struct noCliente *ant;
 struct noCliente *prox;
};

typedef struct noCliente *CLIENTE;
```

Comment: Eu acho que no primeiro exemplo está incompleto; não seria `typedef struct lista { ... } tipo_lista;`?

Comment: Esse `lista` aqui não tem não.

Comment: Então esse `struct lista*` de `ant` e `prox` se refere a outra estrutura...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além dos nomes dos membros a primeira cria um tipo novo que pode ser usado em qualquer lugar do código onde caiba um tipo, então `tipo_lista` passa ser um tipo tanto quanto `int` é um tipo.

Na segunda cria uma estrutura chamada `noCliente`. Isto não cria um tipo, então se quiser instanciá-la em um objeto tem que fazer que colocar o tipo `struct noCliente`, já que o tipo é `struct` com uma especialização.

Claro que logo em seguida essa estrutura é usada para criar um tipo chamado `CLIENTE` que sempre será um ponteiro, portanto ele será um tipo por referência que não é o padrão de estruturas. O uso do ponteiro exigiu a separação entre a declaração da estrutura e a declaração do tipo.

Comment: Então assim resumindo, eu posso utilizar tanto uma quanto outra? O resultado é o mesmo? Porque note uma diferença na declaração das funções também: seguindo o 1 primeiro tenho: `tipo_lista * inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no){` já seguindo o segundo exemplo temos: `void adicionarFilaNormal(CLIENTE filaNormal, int tempoUtilizando){`

Comment: Pode, mas sempre tem uma mais adequada em cada situação. Eu prefiro sempre que possível e fizer sentido já criar o tipo e só criar separado quando não tiver outro jeito. Não tinha as funções na pergunta, mas é justamente o que eu falei, para obter o o tipo já que a referência (o ponteiro embutido) precisa ser da segunda forma, aí ele é abstraído. Se quiser usar por referência no primeiro caso tem que fazer manual. O que pode ser uma boa para deixar mais claro, aí depende da semântica que deseja e do estilo adotado.

Comment: Porque eu tenho um código de estrutura baseado na segunda opção com referência, mas meu professor ensina igual ao primeiro exemplo, então para o projeto dele eu vou fazer baseado na primeira opção, com os ponteiros nos parâmetros das funções.

Comment: @André em geral programadores C gostam mais de serem explícitos mesmo, é uma coisa muita nessa linguagem. Espero que ele faça por isso e não porque todo mundo faz assim. Sempre é importante saber porque está fazendo alguma coisa, até quando dá um espaço.